# Memory questions and functions

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

hope you're all having a great summer!

I'm currently revising for exams and have come up with a couple of questions on a past paper I am stuck with and would appreciate any help/explanation you can provide! :)

Here are the questions;

1.) The function power() should implement the function `n* 2^p` (The output of the `printf()` line should be `5*(2^2) = 20`). Complete the body of the function `power()` using the shift operator.
Why is it sensible to use the shift operator instead of the available power function in `math.h`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int n, int p) {
    << YOUR CODE GOES HERE >>
}

main () {
    printf("%d*(2^%d) = %d\n",5,2,power(5,2));
}
```

2.) Memory is organized in regions called Text, Data, Stack and Heap. The program below defines the variables `a`, `b` and `c`. In which memory region does the content of each variable reside?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 5;

int func1(int x) {
    int b=5;
}

main {
    char * c;

    c = (char*) malloc (a+1);
    func1(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a couple more questions to ask but will see how these goes! I've actually never used stackoverflow before so please go easy if I've done anything wrong!

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: Someone else has done this for you, but in the future, you can format code segments by highlighting them and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Michelle, and thanks mbratch for changing it for me! I apologise for it being formatted so badly in the first post but that was my first post ever on this site! :)

Comment: No problem, as long as you can learn. Also, if you're looking for code (e.g. the `power()` function), you should try it yourself first and then, if it doesn't work, provide your attempts and the result so we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @Michelle , just to ask, if I have more questions should i post a new question or answer this question with a new one?

Comment: If you need a particular answer extended (e.g., "what do you mean by x", or "can you explain what y means"), you should comment on that answer. If it's very closely tied to this question (someone would have to read this to understand), edit your question, otherwise, post a new one. Never post new questions as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 -

because the question wants you to show how to work our power using shift operator; not to show that you know how to use c runtime library.

## 2

```
a - data
b - stack
c - stack
```

he probably wants c - heap but thats not the case. THe contents of c are on the stack

Comment: And he probably meant that the contents of `*c` are on the heap. :)

Comment: Thankyou for such a fast reply! Could I just ask that also for question 1, you could provide a solution to the << YOUR CODE GOES HERE >> part? Also for 2, could you provide any further explanation as to why each a/b/c are such? Many thanks!

Comment: @DanDoughty just take paper and pen. What is 2⁰,2¹,2², and so on in binary? Do you find a pattern?

Comment: Of course it's 2,4,8,16,32 etc... but this asks for an implementation in C using the shift operator which I must admit i'm a complete rookie at! I understand that the answer is shifting 1 bit to the left each time?

Comment: @DanDoughty The keyword was "in binary". Translate that list of numbers you wrote into binary and see if you can spot the pattern.

Comment: 0000, 0100, 0010, 0100, 1000, I understand this part now! I'm just unsure on how to implement this in C, to my understanding you use << for SL, its shifting by one so * << 1;, However I am just unsure as to what to use for the *?

Answer (score 1):

First, I will let you write your own code that is the best way to learn.  But, I will answer the theory behind these questions...

1)  when raising the number 2 to the nth power, is the same as multiplying 2 by itself n times.  But multiplying by 2 is same as doubling a number, and computers store their numbers in base 2.  For example, the binary value for 6 == 0b00110 but when all of the bits are shifted to the left by 1, then 12 == 0b01100, which is same as 6*2.  So, for example, 16 == 4^2 = 4*4 = 4*(2*2)or in binary 16 == 0b010000 == 0b001000*2 = (0b00100)*2*2.

2)  when a variable is declared outside of all routines it is in "global" storage, also probably called "Data".  When a variable is declared within a routine it is an "automatic" variable (meaning that it is automatically) and is allocated on the stack.  When a variable is explicitly allocated, using `malloc` as one example, then it is allocated on the heap.

In C, pointers have two data components or storage elements.  First, is the pointer itself which typically uses only 4 bytes.  Then the data which is whatever length was allocated for the data.  To say anything more will repeat information provided by other answers!

It is a good programming practice to `free` all storage that has been allocated on the heap.  Although, the system should deallocate that storage when `main` exits, this is NOT always guaranteed especially on small or embedded systems.  Thus, the code example should end as:

```
    free(c);
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1>

```
#include <stdio.h>


int power(int n, int p) 

{

return n<<p; // p is the number of bits left-shifted
}

main () 

{
printf("%d*(2^%d) = %d\n",5,2,power(5,2));
}
```

2>

a: data
b: stack
c: stack

Comment: i think power() is false, it should be:
n*( 1 << p );

Comment: May I ask for an explanation for question 2?

Comment: Sorry Saikat I mean the question about data/stack/heap

Comment: @Saikat Kumar Dey: The char pointer is on the stack. It points to the heap

Comment: Consider this:
a is a global variable,
b is a local variable( or automatic variable),
c is a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory on the heap.

A memory representation of a C program is like this:

global variables are stored on the data segment, local( or automatic) variables on the stack and memory is dynamically allocated allocated on the heap.

@Dan, please refer to http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/